# .NET CLR sql scalar function DataTypes

Tags: t-sql, types, clr, user-defined-functions

Briefly: I've written a CLR function that **processes 2 strings in a complex way**.

My dilema: `SqlString` vs `string`. I read on MSDN that the difference is that string takes always the `CurrentCulture` from the current Thread.

But I want to be able to split the input strings: `string.Split()`, etc..

Should I have `SqlString` as parameter type and then convert it to `string`? (I saw that it has an explicit operator). If so, won't it hit the performance? (important). Or should I take directly `string` as the input.?

Anyways, the `SqlString` has .`Value` Property which is a `string` type. If I take this value, what is the sense of having SqlString as parameter types when I'm 'not using it' ?

```
public static bool Foo(SqlString s, SqlString t) {}
```

Comment: Can we assume that the CLR function will live in SQL Server?

Comment: Yep. It is meant to reside on MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

SqlString have conversion operators from others sql types. Try to use it and pass sql vars from other types (int, bigint, etc...).